# Does the limit of function of two variables exist

Tags: real-analysis

If $(a,b) \in \Bbb R^2$ and $a+b=1$,
calculate the following limit or demonstrate that there is none:
$$ \lim_{(x,y) \to  (a,b)}  \frac {y\sin(\pi x)}{x+y-1}$$

I'm doing that: $\lim_{(x,y) \to  (a,b)}  \frac {y\sin(\pi x)}{x+y-1}=\lim_{(x,y) \to  (0,0)}  \frac {(y+b)\sin(\pi (x+a))}{x+y}$
$$ f(x,y)=  \frac { (y+b) \sin(\pi (x+a))}{x+y}  \Rightarrow f(0,\frac {1}{n})=  \frac{(\frac{1}{n}+b) \sin \pi a}{ \frac{1}{n}}= \sin \pi a + n b \sin \pi a  $$
I can get that : If $ a  \in  \Bbb Z \lim _{n \to \infty} f(0,\frac {1}{n})=0  $ and if $a \notin \Bbb   Z $ function doesn't limit.

Why this funtion no limit ,when $ a \in \Bbb Z  $ ?

Help me, please.

Comment: We would like to help you, and we can do that most effectively if you explain what you've tried so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You see that the denumerator $x+y-1$ is null on a line passing by your limit point $(a,b)$. Instead the denumerator is null on the axis $y=0$ and on the lines $x=k$. Hence close to the point $(a,b)$ you will easily find points where the function is arbitrarily large, just take any point very close to the line $x+y-1$ and not too close to the lines mentioned above.

Comment: Or in other words the limit does not exist. Just to expand the function must be approaching the same value regardless of the path that we take as we move in towards $(a,b)$. But to ask again what @defeuer hast asked. What have you tried it so far?

Comment: What about $(a,b)=(1,0)$?

Comment: The three lines $y=0$, $x+y=1$ and $x=1$ all pass by the point $(1,0)$. But this is not a problem, since they are distinct and you can stay arbitrarily close to $x+y=1$ while staying away from the other two lines. This must be stated in terms of $\delta$as: you can stay $\delta$ away from $y=0$ and $x=1$ while staying, let's say, $\delta^2$ close to $x+y=1$.

Comment: I did for $ (a,b) \neq(1,0) $.  I don't understand  justification of reasoning for $(a,b)=(1,0)$.

Comment: (a,b) = (1,0) is not much different from (a,b) = (0,1)... Show us how you did for (a,b)=(0,1)

Comment: I took $ f( \frac {1}{n}, \frac {1}{n})$. I assume that a is an even number.  Then:
$$\lim_{n \to \infty}  f( \frac {1}{n}, \frac {1}{n}) = \frac {b\pi}{2}$$ ,but $\frac {b\pi}{2}=0  \Rightarrow b=0 \Rightarrow a+b \neq 1$

Comment: $(1/n,1/n)$ converges to $(0,0)$ which is not a point you are interested in. I think you should first re-study limits in one variabile, otherwise you will have many difficulties now.